# Angular UI date-picker min Date is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular 1.0.8.
I want to use angular ui datepicker. I want to set minimum date to yesterday.

I had tried min-date option like "min-date='-1d'" but it's not working.

Does anyone have this issue? I need help in setting min-date option.

Thanks and regards,

Jay Patel

Comment: Which version of angular-ui? Prior to 0.11.0 the field was called `min`.

Comment: Then you should be using `min` instead of `min-date` as indicated in the changelog: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: No worries, I had the same issue last week. It's a good idea to take a look in a project's changelog when something does not work like it is described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using angular.ui 0.10.0 version and it's having "min" instead of "min-date".
I changed "min-date" to "min" as per comment and it's working properly

Answer (score -1):

In your Controller you can write ,Use the latest version of date picker from Angular UI it will work , its an example of date of Birth selection

```
min-date="'01/01/1901'"  max-date="maxDate"
```

`$scope.toggleMax = function() {
        $scope.maxDate = $scope.maxDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMax();`