# how to set min date in angularjs when using datepicker-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I am trying to set the min start date.

I have tried using

```
<input id="StartDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="StartDate" datetime-picker="{{'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}" ng-model="vm.StartDate" is-open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.StartDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions"  min-date="2017-07-13 00:00""/>
```

But it is not working. Help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular UI date-picker min Date is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445786/angular-ui-date-picker-min-date-is-not-working)

Comment: I had tried it earlier but it did not work. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

See if this can help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 Min Date {{minDate}}
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-
  model="dt" min="minDate" />
</body>

</html>
 //JS
 var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.minDate = new Date();
   $scope.test = function() {
   $scope.minDate = new Date();
 }
});
```

This new Date will put yourDate in correct format so i will put the example of this code here [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DAeSu8ytJlXT8N4R4C69?p=preview), and one suggetion,

```
var mydate = new Date('2014-04-03');
<input id="StartDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="StartDate" 
datetime-picker="{{'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}" ng-model="vm.StartDate" is-
open="vm.datePickerOpenStatus.StartDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions"  
min-date="mydate"/> //Example
```

This will convert your Date to correct Format :)

Answer (score 1):

Yon modify you **datepicker-options**.
you have already used this directive only you have to add **minDate:today** in this.

```
datepicker-options="{showWeeks:false,minDate:today}"
```

Thanks